# Right way to write a base class that has a function that depends on a inherited member

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes that I want to be derived from a base class, since they share extremely similar functions and member variables, and the only main difference between the two classes will be `SomeClass` vs `SomeOtherClass` for `algo`. What is the best way to approach such a problem?

```
class A
{
    virtual doSomething(); // is it possible to implement it here instead so I don't repeat code?
    int shared_param_1;
    int shared_param_2;
}
class SGBM : public A
{
    SGBM()
    {
        algo->SGBMSpecificFunction();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> algo;

    doSomething()
    {
        algo->compute();
        // long code
    }

    int SGBM_param_1;
    int SGBM_param_2;
}
class BM : public A
{
    BM()
    {
        algo->BMSpecificFunction();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> algo;

    doSomething()
    {
        algo->compute();
        // long completely similar code relying on algo
    }

    int BM_param_1;
    int BM_param_2;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a mostly opinion-based question, but another approach you could take would be to encapsulate the common state into a class and then compose your classes from the common state. (Composition over inheritance). Then make a base class with a pure virtual function. Your derived classes can override that virtual function and use the common state. Or, you could derive a "common" base from the interface that provides storage.

Comment: Is algo an interface or two different classes? If it is an interface, the constructor can instantiate the appropriate object. If it's two different classes, then you must indeed use a virtual function.

Comment: they are two different classes with some similar functions

Comment: You may want to look at the strategy design pattern may be if only the algo changes.

Comment: Let SomeClass and SomeOtherClass inherit SomeBaseClass with a virtual method compute, the classes SGBM and BM well become one.

Comment: Is there a common interface to `SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass`? It looks like they only need to have a common method `compute`.

Comment: @sfun they have a few differing methods that I use in the constructor of BM and SGBM. I've edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most common way to do this is to use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), i.e. `SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` will need to derive from a common interface and you'll inject the algorithm into the base class through the constructor:

```
class Algorithm
{
public:
  virtual ~Algorithm() = default;
  virtual void algo() = 0;
};

class SomeClass : public Algorithm
{
public:
  void algo() override;
};

class SomeOtherClass : public Algorithm
{
public:
  void algo() override;
};

class A
{
public:
  explicit A(std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> algorithm)
    : algorithm{std::move(algorithm)} {}

  void do_something() { algorithm->algo(); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> algorithm;
};

class SGBM : public A
{
public:
  explicit SGBM() : A{std::make_unique<SomeClass>()} {}
};

class BM : public A
{
public:
  explicit BM() : A{std::make_unique<SomeOtherClass>()} {}
};
```

However, that requires you to be able to modify `SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` (or to write wrappers). If that is inconvenient you could also use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for this

```
template <typename Concrete>
class A
{
public:
  void do_something() { static_cast<Concrete*>(this)->algo->compute(); }
};

class SGBM : public A<SGBM>
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> algo;
    friend class A<SGBM>;
};

class BM : public A<BM>
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> algo;
    friend class A<BM>;
};
```

If you need a common base class for `BM` and `SGBM` you need to introduce an additional base class from which `A` then inherits.

Comment: In your `CRTP` example `A` should not inherit from `Concrete`. `A` is the baseclass.

Comment: @super I already noticed that and fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
    virtual doSomething(); // is it possible to implement it here instead so I don't repeat code?
    void doComputing()
    {
        doSomething();
        // common code here
    }
    
    int shared_param_1;
    int shared_param_2;
}
class SGBM : public A
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> algo;
    doSomething()
    {
        algo->compute();
    }
    int SGBM_param_1;
    int SGBM_param_2;
}
class BM : public A
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> algo;
    doSomething()
    {
        algo->compute();
    }
    int BM_param_1;
    int BM_param_2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your are trying to do is called a `Strategy design pattern`. This is a behavioural pattern that allows you to switch from different algo on the fly.

A starting point can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

You may implement it as follows :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// abstract algo
class Algo
{
public:
    void doSomething() { compute(); } // calling compute methods of child classes

    virtual ~Algo() = default;

private:
    virtual void compute() = 0; // Algo::compute() is a virtual function to be implemented in child classes
};

class SGBM  : public Algo
{
private:
    //each algo implements its own compute method
    void compute() override
    {
        std::cout << "Algo SGBM " << std::endl;
    }
};

class BM : public Algo
{
private:
    void compute() override
    {
        std::cout << "Algo BM" << std::endl;
    }
};

//not
class Context
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Algo> algo;

public:
    Context( std::unique_ptr<Algo> new_strategie): algo(std::move(new_strategie))
    {}

    void doSomething()
    {
        algo->doSomething();
    }

    void setAlgorithme(std::unique_ptr<Algo> new_strategie)
    {
        algo = std::move(new_strategie);
    }
};

int main()
{
     //  Treat algo BM
    Context context(std::make_unique<BM>());
    context.doSomething();
        // Treat algo SGBM
    context.setAlgorithme(std::make_unique<SGBM>());
    context.doSomething();


    return 0;
 }
```

This code would output:

```sh
Algo BM                                                                                                                                                                            
Algo SGBM
```